# What dose this means ?: int his sample code?

Tags: typescript

?: this is a Conditional (ternary) operator. But I have seen this in someplace like this:

```
   export interface QueryConfig<I extends any[] = any[]> {
    name?: string;
    text: string;
    values?: I;
    types?: CustomTypesConfig;
}
```

What does **`?:`** and **`<I extends any[] = any[]>`** means over here and how to use it?

Comment: Please take care to tag your questions carefully. There's nothing about JS in your question. Only TS.

Comment: @quentin I didn't know that. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

This is [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/)

`?:` means that the parameter `name` is a string (`:`), but it's optional (`?`)